# Test javascript object existence from Coffee Script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I cope with a coffee script problem when I try to test a javascript object from my it. I have 2 files : a javascript one and a coffee script one which are loaded in this order.

What I need is to define an object in the javascript file:

```
var my_js_obj = {
    string1: "blablabla",
    string2: "blobloblo",
    string3: "blublublu",
};
```

And then I try to get this object from my coffee script file :

```
if not my_js_obj?
  my_js_obj = {}
  console.log "obj does not exist"
else 
  console.log "obj exists"

console.log my_js_obj
```

In my console, I always get an empty object :

```
obj does not exist 
Object {}
```

I don't know if there's an impact but I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_js_obj` is not defined golbally. It's defined as local variable in javascript file. You cannot access it from other file.

If You define it as global variable, then You can access it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought the declaration with var outside any function or block was a global definition. Now, it works using window.my_js_obj in both my javascript file and coffee script file.